# Convert a vector of strings to a deeply-nested JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, rust

I'm trying to get a deeply-nested JSON object from a vector of strings using [the `json` crate](https://docs.rs/json/0.11.10/json/):

```
fn main() {   
    let my_vec = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "barfoo"];
    let mut curr_obj = object!();
    for i in 0..my_vec.len() {
        let name = my_vec[i];
        curr_obj = addObj(curr_obj, name);   
    }
}

fn addObj(mut obj: json::JsonValue, name: &str) -> json::JsonValue {
    obj[name] = json::JsonValue::new_object();
    let retob = obj[name];
    retob.to_owned() // is empty but should be obj["foo"] = object!();
}
```

The object is an empty one here. My desired output looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": {
        "foobar": {
          "barfoo": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the error

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of indexed content
  --> src/main.rs:15:17
   |
15 |     let retob = obj[name];
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^
   |                 |
   |                 cannot move out of indexed content
   |                 help: consider using a reference instead: `&obj[name]`
```

Comment: `addObj` is not idiomatic Rust style, it should be snake_case: `add_obj`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done with a little bit of magic.

```
fn main() {   
    let my_vec = ["foo","bar","baz","foobar","barfoo"];
    let mut curr_obj = object!();
    {
        let mut obj_ref = &mut curr_obj;
        for i in 0..my_vec.len() {
            let name = my_vec[i];
            obj_ref = &mut {obj_ref}[name]; // note the curly braces
        }
    }
    println!("{:?}", curr_obj);
}
```

Mutable reference is moved instead of being reborrowed.

Comment: I remember there was similar question, but I can't find it right now.

Comment: Can you please add more details (or a reference) about the magic of curly braces and the distinction between moving and reborrowing the mutable reference?

Comment: I need to go. Search SO for reborrowing, there is good description.

Comment: you sir - are a genius :)

Answer (score 1):

It's much simpler to use iterator methods:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate json;

fn main() {
    let my_vec = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "foobar", "barfoo"];

    let result = my_vec.iter().rev().fold(object!(), |object, name| {
        object!(name => object)
    });

    println!("{}", json::stringify_pretty(result, 2));
}
```

Produces:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "bar": {
      "baz": {
        "foobar": {
          "barfoo": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```